# SQLyog Job Agent (SJA) for Linux: how to write something like 'all table but a single one'

Tags: linux, sqlyog

I am trying to learn SQLyog Job Agent (SJA). 
I am on a Linux machine, and use SJA from within a bash script by a line command: `./sja  myschema.xml`
I need to sync an almost 100 tables db and its local clone.
Since a single table stores a few config data, which I do not wish to sync, it seems I need to write a myschema.xml where I list all the remaining 99 tables.

Question is: is there a way to write to sync all the table but a single one?

I hope my question is clear. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of sqlyog:You are given the table below,  and the option to generate an xml job file at the end of the database syncronisation wizard reflecting the operation you've opted to perform.  This will in effect list the other 99 tables in the xml file itself for you, but it will give you what you are looking for, and I dont think you would be doing anything in particular with an individual table, since you are specifying all tables in a single element.

[image]